# I am trying to find what operator should be used to extract datetime from Timestamp. The Timestamp column is showing results like 0x0000000002CAE4C0

Tags: datetime

What operator can be used to pull DateTime from a datetime Data_type. The column name is Timestamp which is showing result like 
Timestamp
0x0000000002CAE4C0
0x0000000002CC022C
0x0000000002CB5982
0x0000000002CB84AD
0x0000000002CBD9EF
0x0000000002CC52E9

I tried using 
Select  cast (Timestamp as nvarchar(20)) as testcastDatetime
,   convert (nvarchar,Timestamp,103) as testconvertDatetime

both the above operators are not working. I got an error message 
Operand type clash: timestamp is incompatible with nvarchar

Comment: Where do these timestamp values come from? If some application, which one? On which platform/OS? If some database, which DBMS? Have you got a guess about the range of the timestamps? For now the numbers ring no bell here, sorry.

Comment: The third last hex digit is always either 2, 4 or 9. Wonder if that is coincidental.